# Regular expression to parse escape characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field which accepts only one character but if user enters any escape characters such as \n, \t, \s, etc it should be allowing it even though it has 2 characters.

I am using jquery.validationEngine to validate the text field but failing to parse it as per my desire.

Comment: Well, the regular expression would be `\\[a-z]` or something like `\\[nts]` if you want to be more restrictive. But I assume that alone doesn't solve your problem. So please provide more detailed information and the code you have.

Comment: I need to validate a delimiter on UI side which can be single digit special character like comma or pipe or escape character such as \t. I was able to validate for single character but didn't knew how to validate for escape characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression for that could be

```
[^\\]|\\[tns]
```

Meaning

- any char except a backslash
- or a backslash followed by `t`, `n` or `s`

Note that if you need to put this in a string literal then backslashes must be doubled again (doubled once for the string and doubled again to escape their special meaning in a regexp).

Comment: Thanks for the expression. It works perfectly for me.